# Any WordPress Plugin (Testimonial post by client )

Tags: wordpress

I need a wordpress free Testimonial plugin where user can send reviews and from the UI and i can approved

Comment: How would this differ from approving comments?

Comment: i want to add a testimonial slider. testimonial by client..testimonial feedback